# jquery outlineing columns

Tags: jquery

I want to ouline one column in a thin red colour so far i have seen this
http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/GtAwW/

but this is when it is clicked i would like it outlined when the page loads, the reason for this is because this column will hold the errors so its easier for the user to see

i.e 
the column which just has **asf** i would like that outlined in thin red

is this possible

COULD THIS BE DONE FOR THE HEADER TO COLUMN
FORGOT TO SAY THIS NEW LINK

http://jsfiddle.net/GtAwW/42/

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the required logic on page load it will work as you want.

Try this.

```
$('td:contains("asdf")').each(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $(this).prev('td').toggleClass('selected-right');
        $(this).parent().prev('tr').find('td:nth-child('+(this.cellIndex+1)+')').toggleClass('selected-bottom');
});
```

​
Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/GtAwW/41/

I would recommend you to apply a class to all such td's which will show error message and control the styling through css.

Comment: ok this works but sorry i forgot tot say can this be done by getting the column name ?

Comment: You can provide a class name and use class name to select the required column.

Comment: A column doesn't really exist, only rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
$('td:contains("asdf")').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('red');
});
$('.red').first().attr('style','border-top:1px solid red;');
$('.red').last().attr('style','border-bottom:1px solid red;');
```

I've coded up a fiddle for you - [http://jsfiddle.net/rTKDh/](http://jsfiddle.net/rTKDh/1)